# What happens in the plane in Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was injected into the doctor at the beginning of TDKR](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21790/what-was-injected-into-the-doctor-at-the-beginning-of-tdkr)

In the plane scene in *The Dark Knight Rises*, after Bane and his men take over the plane, they lower a body bag and appear to give the physicist a blood transfusion. Is there any explanation for why this was done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They transfused some of the physicists blood into a cadaver to make authorities think that dr. Pavel had died in the plane crash (there was a news report alluding to this later in the movie)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

They had a dead body in the bag, by transferring the blood from the physicist they are embedding his DNA into the corpse. The idea is to have the physicist id'ed as one of the people who died in the crash.

Comment: 6second difference, same answer!

Comment: You win this round...